# Angular material Tree icon border issue

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am choosing [angular material tree component](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview#nested-tree)   but I can't remove the icon border:
[image]
I have already imported MatIconModule

```
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatTreeModule} from '@angular/material/tree';
imports: [MatTreeModule, MatIconModule..]
```

The implementation is exactly the same reported in the attached link.
Any help will be appreciated

I'm trying to integrate a new components to into an existing project and it seems that I also cannot use some bootstrap classes, I should find what is blocking styles.

Comment: Hey can you please create stackblize e.g to find out what exactly you have done?

Comment: By default there are no borders, check your browser's developer tools "Computed" tab for css rules targeting these elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try to manipulate mat-icon-button's border.

```
.mat-icon-button {
    border-bottom: unset !important;
}
```